# java error in 2 different methods: missing return statement

Tags: java

I have error "missing return statement" for 2 nonvoid methods:

Method 1:

```
private boolean checkBox(int val, int i, int j) {
    if(0<=i && i<=2 && 0<=j && j<=2){for(i=0;i<=2;i++){for(j=0;j<=2;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(0<=i && i<=2 && 3<=j && j<=5){for(i=0;i<=2;i++){for(j=3;j<=5;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(0<=i && i<=2 && 6<=j && j<=8){for(i=0;i<=2;i++){for(j=6;j<=8;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(3<=i && i<=5 && 0<=j && j<=2){for(i=3;i<=5;i++){for(j=0;j<=2;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(3<=i && i<=5 && 3<=j && j<=5){for(i=3;i<=5;i++){for(j=3;j<=5;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(3<=i && i<=5 && 6<=j && j<=8){for(i=3;i<=5;i++){for(j=6;j<=8;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(6<=i && i<=8 && 0<=j && j<=2){for(i=6;i<=8;i++){for(j=0;j<=2;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(6<=i && i<=8 && 3<=j && j<=5){for(i=6;i<=8;i++){for(j=3;j<=5;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
    if(6<=i && i<=8 && 6<=j && j<=8){for(i=6;i<=8;i++){for(j=6;j<=8;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}
```

}

Method 2:

```
  private int solveMethod(int val, int i, int j){
    if(i<SIZE-1){
    if(j<=SIZE-1){
    if(isEmpty(i, j)==true){
            if(model[i][j]==0){val=1;}
            if(tryValue(val, i, j)==false){
                    if(model[i][j]<SIZE) solveMethod(model[i][j]+1, i, j);

                    else{     
                            bigloop:while(i>0){
                                            while(j>0){
                                                    j--;
                                                    if(isEmpty(i, j)==true && model[i][j]<SIZE) break bigloop;
                                            }
                                            i--;
                                            j=8;
                            }
                            solveMethod(model[i][j]+1, i, j);
                    }
            }else{solveMethod(val, i, j+1);}
    }else{solveMethod(val, i, j+1);}
    }else{solveMethod(val, i+1, 0);}
    }else{return i;}
```

How to think about it (both cases) and how to correct it. Please be pedagogical ;-) - I'm a java newbie.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Method 1: Your for loops might complete without returning, so the method would not hit a return statement.

Comment: @khelwood it's not loops, it's the conditions: there's no guarantee that any of the outermost conditions are met.

Comment: Method 2: Your method only hits a return statement if it meets that final `else` clause.

Comment: `solveMethod(model[i][j]+1, i, j)` What's the point in calling this method if you ignore its result? You neither (***hint***) return it or save it in a variable.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think it's the loops. For each line, _either_ a loop runs, _else_ the program returns. If the loop completes without returning, the method doesn't hit a return statement.

Comment: Method 1 would be a lot simpler if you defined `int imin = (i / 3) * 3, jmin = (j / 3) * 3;`, and just did loops like `for (i = imin; i < imin + 3; ++i)`. Then you wouldn't need all that repeated code.

Comment: @khelwood replace the loops with unconditional return statements; you'd still have the same issue.

Comment: @AndyTurner Then the first line would be `if (.....) { return false; } else { return true; }`. The method would definitely hit a return. In fact all the rest of the method would be unreachable.

Comment: @khelwood ah, I see.

Answer (score 0):

> missing return statement

It means at least one control flow in program exists that doesn't return value.

For Method 1, i'm explaining:

```
if(0<=i && i<=2 && 0<=j && j<=2)
{
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            if(model[i][j]==val) // if this is false in all the iterations
                                 // method won't be returning any value.
                                 // hence the error.
                return false;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

Now, you can look similarly for Method 2.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you declare a method with a return type, the compiler ensures that you return in any case a value compatible with this type.

The compiler cannot guess that your method will be called only in bounded cases, so it supposes than if a condition may not be true or false, it have to be considered in the check if a value is returned or not in the method.

For example in `checkBox()` method, you have multiple independent if else if blocks.
But if you never enter in any of these `if`, you don't return value.

In `solveMethod()` method, you have also some cases where you don't return values.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable at the start of the whole method with the same type as that defined in the method constructor.

```
private boolean checkBox(int val, int i, int j) {
    boolean  return_val = false;
```

then... you just return it at the very end before the final  `}`

```
    ....
    if(0<=i && i<=2 && 0<=j && j<=2){for(i=0;i<=2;i++){for(j=0;j<=2;j++){if(model[i][j]==val) return false;}}}else{return true;}

    return return_val;
}
```

You could also just do   `return false;`  at the end of the first method since its a `boolean`

for the second method  its an integer so, maybe `return -1`  or `return 0`  would work?  If you have to, implement a condition on whatever thing is calling the second method to perform some `error checking` in case that one `return 0` condition happens.

You always have to return a typed object which matches the type specified here:

`private int solveMethod(int val, int i, int j){`

Specifically,

`private int solveMethod`

where `int` specifies the return type